Problem to convert from ASCII to integers in Assembly AT&T 32 bit
ASM newbie here. I'm trying to convert in ASM AT&T (32-bit version) the following ASCII text from ASCII to integer (skipping the commas (44 in ASCII) and newlines (10 in ASCII)):
1,10,2,2\n2,7,6,7\n3,9,6,5\n4,11,8,6\n5,3,7,6\n
6,12,11,3\n7,10,10,7\n8,4,2,1\n9,3,1,4\n10,5,8,8
Using this loop which calls an atoi function:
conversion_loop:
    xor %ecx, %ecx
    cmpl $0, (%esi)
    je id_start
    cmpl $10, (%esi)
    je newline_conversion_loop
    mov $44, %cl
    call str2int
    movb %al, converted_int(%edi)

    jmp end_loop

newline_conversion_loop:
    movb $10, %cl
    call str2int
    movb %al, converted_int(%edi)

end_loop:
    inc %esi
    inc %edi
    jnp conversion_loop

The function called is this:
str2int:
    push %ebx              
    push %edx

    xor %eax, %eax          
    xor %ebx, %ebx         

while:
    mov (%esi), %bl        

    cmp $0, %bl             
    je end
    
    cmp %cl, %bl            
    je end

    sub $48, %bl            
    mov $10, %edx          
    mul %edx                
    add %ebx, %eax          

    inc %esi                
    jmp while
end:
    pop %edx                
    pop %ebx
    ret

Everything works fine until I reach the fourth number to convert, starting from which it continues to give me 0 as output. I can't figure out why.
I tried to search the cause of this problem in GDB, but I couldn't find it.
This is the ASCII content of the variable (label) to which %esi points:
(gdb) x/128bd $esi

0x804a194:  49  44  49  48  44  50  44  50

0x804a19c:  10  50  44  55  44  54  44  55

0x804a1a4:  10  51  44  57  44  54  44  53

0x804a1ac:  10  52  44  49  49  44  56  44

0x804a1b4:  54  10  53  44  51  44  55  44

0x804a1bc:  54  10  54  44  49  50  44  49

0x804a1c4:  49  44  51  10  55  44  49  48

0x804a1cc:  44  49  48  44  55  10  56  44

0x804a1d4:  52  44  50  44  49  10  57  44

0x804a1dc:  51  44  49  44  52  10  49  48

0x804a1e4:  44  53  44  56  44  56  10  0

This is the content of the variable (label) converted_int to which %edi points:

(gdb) x/8bd &converted_int

0x804a214:  1   10  2   0   0   0   0   0

After this, it exits from the loop.
The variables are correctly declared (I guess):
file_content:       .space 128

converted_int:      .space 48


For starters you use 32 bit operations instead of 8. You only skip \n in the conversion_loop but not in str2int so the sequence 2\n2 will be parsed wrong.

@sobekan please mark answer as complete if it fixes your solution

Issue
Like @Jester mentioned in comment, the issue might be related to how you are handling the characters in the loop and in the str2int function. The issue is with how you are processing the end of the string or how you are handling newlines.
Updated code:
.section .data
file_content:       .ascii "1,10,2,2\n2,7,6,7\n3,9,6,5\n4,11,8,6\n5,3,7,6\n6,12,11,3\n7,10,10,7\n8,4,2,1\n9,3,1,4\n10,5,8,8\0"
converted_int:      .space 48

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    lea file_content, %esi
    lea converted_int, %edi

conversion_loop:
    xor %ecx, %ecx               # Clear %ecx (no character to skip)
    movb (%esi), %al             # Load the current character
    test %al, %al                # Test if end of string (null byte)
    je end_loop

    cmpb $44, %al                # Check if character is a comma
    je skip_char
    cmpb $10, %al                # Check if character is a newline
    je skip_char

    call str2int                 # Convert character to integer
    movb %al, (%edi)             # Store result in converted_int
    inc %edi                     # Move to next position in converted_int

skip_char:
    inc %esi                     # Move to next character in file_content
    jmp conversion_loop          # Repeat loop

end_loop:
    # Exit the program (using Linux syscall)
    mov $1, %eax                 # sys_exit
    xor %ebx, %ebx               # Return code 0
    int $0x80                    # Call kernel

str2int:
    push %ebx
    push %edx

    xor %eax, %eax               # Clear %eax (result)
    xor %ebx, %ebx               # Clear %ebx (character)

convert_loop:
    movb (%esi), %bl             # Load the current character
    cmp %cl, %bl                 # Compare with terminating character (if any)
    je convert_end               # If match, end conversion
    cmpb $0, %bl                 # Check if end of string (null byte)
    je convert_end
    cmpb $44, %bl                # Check if comma
    je convert_end
    cmpb $10, %bl                # Check if newline
    je convert_end

    sub $48, %bl                 # Convert ASCII to integer
    imul $10, %eax               # Multiply result by 10 (shift left)
    add %ebx, %eax               # Add current digit

    inc %esi                     # Move to next character
    jmp convert_loop             # Repeat conversion loop

convert_end:
    pop %edx
    pop %ebx
    ret

Notes
1. Main Loop:
The conversion_loop reads characters from file_content.
Skips commas and newlines, converts other characters to integers using str2int.
2. str2int Function:
Converts a sequence of characters to an integer until it encounters a comma, newline, or null byte.
Handles multi-digit numbers correctly.
3.Exit:
Properly exits using a syscall for clean termination.

Your solution exhibits Buffer Overflow! The conversion_loop continues in the memory behind the terminating zero.


jnp conversion_loop


Probably a mere typo, but still: jnp should be jmp

cmpl $0, (%esi)
je id_start
cmpl $10, (%esi)


The source contains bytes, therefore using cmpl is wrong: use cmpb.

cmp $0, %bl             
je end


In case the str2int finds a null, precaution is in order! Currently the main loop (str2int's caller) just increments %esi and happily continues behind the source string.
I see no benefit in detecting whether it's 10 or 44 that terminates the number before calling str2int.
Below is my suggestion:
    lea    file_content, %esi
    lea    converted_int, %edi

begin_loop:
    cmpb   $0, (%esi)
    je     end_loop         # Run loop while not at end-of-string
    call   str2int          # -> %eax, %ecx, %esi
    movb   %al, (%edi)      # Store to byte-sized array
    inc    %edi
    inc    %esi             # Skips either 0, 10 or 44
    test   %ecx, %ecx       # Did we skip 0 ?
    jnz    begin_loop       # No

end_loop:
    xor    %ebx, %ebx
    mov    $1, %eax         # sys_exit
    int    $0x80
# --------------------------
# IN (%esi) OUT (%eax,%ecx,%esi)
str2int:
    xor    %eax, %eax       # Result
str2int_loop:
    movzbl (%esi), %ecx     # Load character
    test   %cl, %cl
    jz     str2int_end      # End-of-string
    cmpb   $10, %cl
    je     str2int_end      # Newline
    cmpb   $44, %cl
    je     str2int_end      # Comma

    imul   $10, %eax        # Result = Result * 10 + ASCII - 48
    add    %ecx, %eax
    sub    $48, %eax

    inc    %esi
    jmp    str2int_loop
str2int_end:
    ret

